No exp of trading need help bought bitcoin
I am a beginner and have recently purchased some bitcoin about £150 worth - can anyone give me a basic guide on how everything works, how to trade what to look out for.  i have bought this on the crypto app but have no idea how to trade LOL!  So looking for some advise starting from most basic! Thanks

Welcome to Bitcoin.stackexchange. You will find it helpful to take the [tour]. This website works best when you ask one question at a time and make the questions very specific. For example, you should say which "crypto app" you are using as there are hundreds, or maybe thousands of them. This question is likely to be voted for closure as too general - using a search engine can be a better way of getting answers to broad general questions. See New to Bitcoin, How to get started
